# Update HTML table without reloading the page or click button using PHP

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I am new to PHP and I want to refresh the HTML table when I insert a list of data using the SQL command in XAMPP.

> This is the `index.php` that displays fetches data from the database and display it in the table.

```
`<?php

include("connect_db.php");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

<style>
    table,tr,th,td{
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    table{
        width: 60%;
    }

</style>

</head>

<body>
    
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> Data User Id </th>
                <th> Date </th>
                <th> Time</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <?php
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM data_table WHERE data_user_id = 1001 ORDER BY data_id DESC");
            while ($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
               
                echo "<tr >";
                echo "<td >".$res['data_user_id']."</td>";
                echo "<td >".$res['data_date']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$res['data_times']."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
    
        ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>`
```

> Create connection to database. connect_db.php

```
<?php


$server_name = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "user_db";

$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];


$conn = new mysqli($server_name,$username,$password,$database);

if (!$conn){

    die ('Connection Failed: '.mysqli_connect_error());

}

?>
```

> And it display like this. I want to refresh the table data without reloading or click button when I add a list of data using SQL command in XAMPP. I saw a lot reference from the internet that uses AJAX and JQUERY but most of them uses buttons. I humbly request for your help and code reference . Thank you

[image]

Comment: If you use separate commands to inject data, then use ajax to reload say 5 seconds the DIV containing the data

Comment: As above, use a timer in Javascript to force the reload.

Comment: Can you give me a reference?

Comment: And there's [websockets](https://javascript.info/websocket).

Answer (score 0):

Get the latest data using an jQuery ajax call (on button click) to reload table content without page reload and don't directly use MySQL query in html.

Thanks

Comment: Well, sir  I want to get the latest data automatically ( without  button click)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Ajax to reload your table without clicking on any button .. just run your query every x seconds, but beware, I'm not sure that this kind of practice is recommended .... in your js file :

```
setInterval(function(){ 
//send your ajax request every 15 second  
 }, 15000);
```